# MySQL Group where any 3 of 5 columns match

Tags: mysql

I am searching an addresses table for duplicates, using SOUNDEX to find the duplicates. This works fine, and it requires all 5 soundex columns to match in order to group

However, I want to GROUP where ANY 3 of my 5 SOUNDEX columns match.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT `Address`.`id`, 
    SOUNDEX(`Address`.`address_company_name`) as soundex_address_company_name,
    SOUNDEX(`Address`.`contact_name`) as soundex_contact_name,
    SOUNDEX(`Address`.`street_address`) as soundex_street_address,
    SOUNDEX(`Address`.`suburb`) as soundex_suburb,
    SOUNDEX(`Address`.`city`) as soundex_city,
    `Address`.`address_country_id`,
    `Address`.`address_zone_id`,
    `Address`.`postcode`, 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    `addresses` AS `Address` 
WHERE 
     ((`Address`.`address_company_name` IS NOT NULL) 
     OR (`Address`.`contact_name` IS NOT NULL))  
GROUP BY 
    SOUNDEX(address_company_name),
    SOUNDEX(contact_name),
    SOUNDEX(street_address),
    SOUNDEX(suburb),
    SOUNDEX(city),
    address_country_id,
    address_zone_id,
    postcode
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

I understand how to do this with multiple queries, ie: loop through each address in our database and then re-query the database for addresses which match any 3 of the 5 columns, however I am hoping to do this in fewer queries as the above query executes very quickly.

I also understand that were this possible, some records may be grouped multiple times, I don't mind if this is the case but I am unsure whether this flies in the face of MySQL logic?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Currently the output is any address which is duplicated whereby the SOUNDEX of address_company_name, contact_name, street_address, suburb and city match some other record in the database. (and the address_country_id, address_zone_id and postcode also match). However, I would like it such that if any 3 of the soundex fields match some other record it is returned as a duplicate. for example:
SOUNDEX of address_company_name, street_address and suburb match another record, but contact_name and city don't, as we have 3 matches, it would be considered a duplicate and returned.

Comment: From my own experience it sounds like you will have to do separate queries with a union this would take 10 sub queries unioned together and then grouped to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT a.id, b.id id2, COUNT(*) no_matches
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, 
         column_id,
         CASE column_id 
            WHEN 1 THEN SOUNDEX(address_company_name)
            WHEN 2 THEN SOUNDEX(contact_name)
            WHEN 3 THEN SOUNDEX(street_address)
            WHEN 4 THEN SOUNDEX(suburb)
            WHEN 5 THEN SOUNDEX(city)
         END column_value
    FROM addresses a CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT 1 column_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
  ) i
   WHERE address_company_name IS NOT NULL
      OR contact_name IS NOT NULL
) a CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT id, 
         column_id,
         CASE column_id 
            WHEN 1 THEN SOUNDEX(address_company_name)
            WHEN 2 THEN SOUNDEX(contact_name)
            WHEN 3 THEN SOUNDEX(street_address)
            WHEN 4 THEN SOUNDEX(suburb)
            WHEN 5 THEN SOUNDEX(city)
         END column_value
    FROM addresses a CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT 1 column_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
  ) i
   WHERE address_company_name IS NOT NULL
      OR contact_name IS NOT NULL
) b
 WHERE a.column_value = b.column_value
   AND a.id < b.id
 GROUP BY a.id, b.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Sample output:

```
| ID | ID2 | NO_MATCHES |
|----|-----|------------|
|  1 |   2 |          4 |
|  4 |   5 |          3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8faae/2)** demo

Comment: Hey paterm. Thanks for your answer. I tried running this on my database of 9,000 addresses and after 10 minutes I had to reset WAMP, the query still hadn't completed.

Comment: Is the only way to do this using multiple Unions? I figured there would be some way to do this using an inner join ON multiple columns, however in my attempts to do this I get a huge result set, > 100,000 (repeated columns etc). It just seems like doing so many unions would be very intensive, however I figured doing an INNER JOIN would only perform two queries, then simply merge the results.